# Add seconds to current date/time and generate only hour/minute/seconds

Tags: sql, database, date

good morning!

I have a little problem, could you help?

I need to add 2 seconds to my current time.

From my date/time I need to add 2 seconds and get only hour/minute/seconds.

I tried in a way like sum. I concatenate hour/minute/second and add 2 seconds.

But it's not being assertive... =/

Below is the method I tried:

```
DECLARE @ACTUAL_DATE VARCHAR (6);
SET @ACTUAL_DATE = (SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(), 'HHmmss'));

DECLARE @SUM_HOUR varchar (10);
SET @SUM_HOUR = (CAST(@ACTUAL_DATE as int)) + 2;

DECLARE @NEXT_HOUR VARCHAR (46);
SET @NEXT_HOUR = (SELECT Hr_Proxima_Transmissao FROM TBJDCTC_AGENDA_TRANSMISSAO WHERE Arquivo_TP = 'ACTC101');

PRINT @ACTUAL_DATE;
PRINT @SUM_HOUR;
PRINT @NEXT_HOUR;
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `DATEADD` function. You can add 2 seconds to a `DATE` like so

```
  DATEADD(second,2,@ACTUEL_DATE)
```

Comment: It doesn't work... =/
The format looks like this: Aug 14 2214 12:00 AM
I only need hour/minute/second concatenated and added to 2 seconds. =/

Comment: I achieved!
Via https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-convert-date-functions-and-formats/

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it with the following command:

```
DECLARE @SOMAHORA VARCHAR (30);
SET @SOMAHORA = REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND, 2, GetDate()), 24), ':', '');
```